# How to make the value in the cell change when the conditional formatting cell color changes?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is excel for recording work progress.
So, the cells that are green are based on the start date and end date, for example the start date is in the first week of January 2 and finishes on January 4, so the task is done for 2 days and only 2 cells will be colored green. When the week display is replaced, the green cell will disappear. I want the number I entered in the green cell to also disappear but it doesn't work.Is there a way when the week changes, and the cell isn't green, the value will follow the cell? vba code better.

Comment: Welcome! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Please show us the VBA code that you have tried so far.